# Data Deduplication and Grouping Aggregation Queries in ES Index

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm currently facing a challenge regarding the processing of Elasticsearch index data, and I'm looking for assistance and solutions here.

I have an ES index that contains two fields: fingerprint and type. I need to process this data to fulfill the following requirements:

**Data Deduplication:** I aim to deduplicate the data based on the fingerprint field, eliminating duplicate records. It's important to note that identical fingerprint values might correspond to different type values, **and the deduplication process should prioritize the fingerprint value.**

**Grouping Aggregation:** After completing the deduplication process, I intend to group the data by the type field and then retrieve the data count for each type.

Due to the substantial data volume, it's not feasible to traverse the deduplicated data. Thus, I'm seeking a more effective processing method. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could share some solution approaches or example code, enabling me to address this challenge.

Thank you for taking the time to read my request for assistance. I'm eagerly anticipating your valuable insights and suggestions!

I have attempted the following methods:

[Query statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnqSq.png)

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLib2.png)

**But this query is unable to aggregate the results of the type aggregation.**

Comment: Have you had a look at the `composite` aggregation which allows you to paginate over all your deduplicated buckets?